# Complex to exponential form

Tags: complex-numbers

I have EE example and hope someone can help me with it.
$I=4,2-7,3i$

Determine the real standard form.

Solution: $I=8,42e^{-1,04i}$

Problem: I dont understand how they got -1,04, because I got 60$^\circ$.

Comment: 60 degrees is about 1.04 radians. Use radians.

Comment: Note that $I$ is in quadrant $\operatorname{II}$ and so your angle should be negative.

Answer (score 1):

Your number is essentially

$$z = a + ib$$

The polar form is given by

$$z = |z|e^{i\theta}$$

Where $|z| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ which in your case is

$$|z| = \sqrt{4.2^2 + (-7.3^2)} = 8.42$$

And that is good.

Now

$$\theta = \arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right) = \arctan\frac{-7.3}{4.2} = -60$$

Which means: you're right!

BUT... It expresses the measure in RADIANS, and we find that

$$60^{\circ} = 1.04\ \text{rad}$$

Answer (score 0):

Generalize the problem, when $\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$:
$$\text{z}=\Re\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]i=\left|\text{z}\right|e^{\left(\arg\left(\text{z}\right)+2\pi k\right)i}=\left|\text{z}\right|\cos\left(\arg\left(\text{z}\right)+2\pi k\right)+\left|\text{z}\right|\sin\left(\arg\left(\text{z}\right)+2\pi k\right)i$$
Where $\left|\text{z}\right|=\sqrt{\Re^2\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{z}\right]}$, $\arg\left(\text{z}\right)$ is the complex argument of $\text{z}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

---

In your problem, when $\text{z}=\text{I}=4.2-7.3i$:

1. $$\left|4.2-7.3i\right|=\sqrt{4.2^2+7.3^2}=\frac{\sqrt{7093}}{10}$$
2. $$\arg\left(4.2-7.3i\right)=-\arctan\left(\frac{7.3}{4.2}\right)=-\arctan\left(\frac{73}{42}\right)\approx-1.0487\space\text{radians}\approx-60.09^\circ$$